# WEP WiFi Hotspot

Tags: pi-3, hotspot, wpa

So I want to use my DS online again, and what I need to do is get a router with WEP seurity, or a router without security. So I decided to use my Pi 3 B as a WiFi hotspot. But all the stuff I find is for WPA and the like. Is there a way to make a hotspot without security or a WEP security?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Nintendo DS online services have been shut down years ago.

Comment: Sorry, not original DS servers, a replacement service Wiimmfi works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [hostapd config file options](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf). I've stripped out the bits for WEP.

```
# IEEE 802.11 specifies two authentication algorithms. hostapd can be
# configured to allow both of these or only one. Open system authentication
# should be used with IEEE 802.1X.
# Bit fields of allowed authentication algorithms:
# bit 0 = Open System Authentication
# bit 1 = Shared Key Authentication (requires WEP)
# Use either
auth_algs=3
#or auth_algs=2
#
# Static WEP key configuration
#
# The key number to use when transmitting.
# It must be between 0 and 3, and the corresponding key must be set.
# default: not set
#
wep_default_key=0
#
# The WEP keys to use.
# A key may be a quoted string or unquoted hexadecimal digits.
# The key length should be 5, 13, or 16 characters, or 10, 26, or 32
# digits, depending on whether 40-bit (64-bit), 104-bit (128-bit), or
# 128-bit (152-bit) WEP is used.
# Only the default key must be supplied; the others are optional.
# default: not set
wep_key0=123456789a
#wep_key1="vwxyz"
#wep_key2=0102030405060708090a0b0c0d
#wep_key3=".2.4.6.8.0.23"
#
# WEP rekeying (disabled if key lengths are not set or are set to 0)
# Key lengths for default/broadcast and individual/unicast keys:
# 5 = 40-bit WEP (also known as 64-bit WEP with 40 secret bits)
# 13 = 104-bit WEP (also known as 128-bit WEP with 104 secret bits)
#wep_key_len_broadcast=5
#wep_key_len_unicast=5
# Rekeying period in seconds. 0 = do not rekey (i.e., set keys only once)
#wep_rekey_period=300
```

Should get your AP doing the ancient, insecure protocol that your Nintendo DS needs.

Comment: So I copy this and put it in sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf?

Comment: You'll need to ADD those statements to whatever other stuff is in your hostapd configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

To use none security or to use WEP security you have just to configure **wpa_supplicant** in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant*.conf`. For example I take [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) in section **Configure wpa_supplicant as access point**. Just use this configuration for an unsecured access point:

```
cat > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=NONE
    frequency=2437
}
```

For a WEP secured connection you can look at

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf.gz | less
```

There you will find two examples for a *network* block nearly the end:

```
# Shared WEP key connection (no WPA, no IEEE 802.1X)
network={
        ssid="static-wep-test"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        wep_key0="abcde"
        wep_key1=0102030405
        wep_key2="1234567890123"
        wep_tx_keyidx=0
        priority=5
}


# Shared WEP key connection (no WPA, no IEEE 802.1X) using Shared Key
# IEEE 802.11 authentication
network={
        ssid="static-wep-test2"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        wep_key0="abcde"
        wep_key1=0102030405
        wep_key2="1234567890123"
        wep_tx_keyidx=0
        priority=5
        auth_alg=SHARED
}
```

I haven't tested it but I think **for an access point** you have to add `mode=2` and a `frequency=` line.

Comment: That doesn't answer the op's question. He wants to make a WEP AP not connect to one.

Comment: @Dougie The first network block definitely creates an access point with `mode=2`. For the WEP network blocks I advised the OP to add `mode=2` and a `frequency=` for an access point. So what? Maybe there are some quirks because I haven't tested it. Tell me if so.